# Regarding console_unlock call from linux kernel context

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded-linux

I use linux kernel v4.9.0 for two core armv7 based platform.
The THREAD_SIZE parameter which decides stack size of the kernel thread is by default set at 8KB.

My question here is I want to call `printk()` from this thread. Can I do this? Because I get kernel panics when I put quite a few printks in that kernel thread context.

Comment: What thread you are talking about? `printk()` can be used in many contexts with rare exceptions.

Comment: I have created a custom kernel thread in my driver which does some monitoring. Let me provide the snippet of kernel panic that I get while It seems that I am printing from this custom thread